# Dealing with capturing error in python - won't "try" and will crash script

Tags: python, exception

I must be doing something wrong that I can't figure out from other resources on teh web.

At one point in my script I try to run:

```
username= win32security.LookupAccountSid(None, ace[2])[0]
```

From which I get and error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#10>", line 1, in <module>
   win32security.LookupAccountSid(None, ace[2])[0]
error: (1332, 'LookupAccountSid', 'No mapping between account names and security IDs was done.')
```

I figured out this happens when you have a security registry for which there no longer is a user so it shows up on the permissions as S-1-xxx...

In order to get the script to move on I wrote:

```
try:
    username= win32security.LookupAccountSid(None, ace[2])[0]
except:
    nouser +=1
```

This code will still give the error and stop my script. How can I get my script to ignore when this error happens?

Comment: try `import win32security` and `except win32security.error`

Comment: And *never* use a bare except clause unless you reraise the exception, nor assume whatever about what the error is.

Comment: 'never use a bare except clause' - this is the new 'goto is evil'. if you know what you're doing (or actually don't care about the _type_ of the exception) it's totally valid to use a plain `except`. it's widely used in the standard library - a quick `grep -nr except: .` in my usr/lib/python2.7 returned over 1350 lines...